# How to replace values in all columns in r

Tags: r, dataframe, replace

Just a quick question: how can I replace some values with others if these values are present in all the dataframe's column? Functions like  `mapvalues` and  `recode` work only if the column is specified, but in my case the dataframe has 89 columns so that would be time-consuming.

For the sake of clarity, take in consideration the following example. I want to replace [NULL] with another value.

Example:

```
a <- c("NULL",2,"NULL")
b <- c(3, "NULL", 1)

df <- data.frame(a, b)
df

           a         b
0      NULL          3
1          2      NULL 
2      NULL          1
```

The difference between the example and my case is that the dataset is [35383 x 89], and the values I want to replace are more than one.

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the existing example.

Comment: If you want to replace `NULL` with 0 you can do `df[df == 'NULL'] <- 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An extension to the comment by Ronak Shah. You can add 0 if you want like that. Or you can replace it with desired values, if you like that.

For example, replace the NULLs with mean of the respective columns:

```
#Run a loop to convert the characters into numbers because for your case it is all characters
#This will change the NULL to NAs.

for (i in colnames(df)){
  df[,i] <- as.numeric(df[,i])
}

#Now replace the NAs with the mean of the column

for (i in colnames(df)){
  df[,i][is.na(df[,i])] <- mean(df[,i], na.rm=TRUE)
}
```

You can similarly do this for median also. Let me know in the comment if you have any doubts.

Answer (score 2):

For starters, I have added a few more rows to your example to better show how the code works

```
df

#     a    b
#1  NULL    3
#2     2 NULL
#3  NULL    1
#4     a   14
#5     1    a
#6    14    5
```

First, create two vectors: one with whe values you want to replace (pattern) and one with replacements in the same order. To make sure you have done it right, put them together in a data frame and take a look at the rows (this will also help in next step)

In this case, I want NULL to be 0, "a" to be "alpha", and so on, as shown below

```
pattern <- c("NULL", "a", 14, 1)
replacement <- c(0, "alpha", "fourteen", "one")
subs <- data.frame(pattern, replacement)
subs

#  pattern replacement
#1    NULL           0
#2       a       alpha
#3      14    fourteen
#4       1         one
```

To finish it, we will make a `for` tthat each time we will pick a pattern and its replacement from the subs data frame we created, and with these values execute a `map_df()`. This function iterates over the columns from our original data frame (df) and apply the `gsub()` function with the pattern and replacement

```
for (i in 1:nrow(subs)) {
  df <- map_df(df, gsub, pattern = subs$pattern[i], replacement = subs$replacement[i])
}

df

#   a        b        
#1  0        3       
#2  2        0       
#3  0        one     
#4  alpha    fourteen
#5  one      alpha   
#6  fourteen 5
```

I hope this was clear. Let me know if you have any doubts